# If statement is not working correctly despite the two sides being the same

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim FormOpen As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\AndTime\OpenForm1")
TextBox1.Text = FormOpen
If FormOpen = "1" Then
    Form1.Show()
End If
```

I put the "TextBox1.Text = FormOpen" to test if the file is reading correctly, which it is , the text box displays 1 without any spaces or any other catheters before or after the "1".

Therefore the problem must be something to do with the if statement

Comment: You know "C:\AndTime\OpenForm1" is not a file right?

Comment: it is , just hasnt got a file extension, does it have to have .txt at the end to work propperly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You didn't specify the encoding. So it used UTF-8 as the default, but if you used something like notepad to create it, the encoding maybe off.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.readalltext

Try using ASCII as in the example at the link above, see if that resolves the issue. If it does, then it's just a simple matter of making sure that you're using the same encoding to read the file that was used to write the file.

Comment: thank you it , it turned out to be i saved the text file under unicode on notepad, changed it to ANSI at them my code finally worked

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim FormOpen As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\AndTime\OpenForm1")
TextBox1.Text = FormOpen
If FormOpen = "1" Then
    Form1.Show()
End If
```

The argument to `ReadAllText()` needs to be the complete path and filename. If the file has an extension it needs to be there. If the file is `OpenForm1.txt`, and it's in a directory named "AndTime" on the C: drive, the string needs to be `"C:\AndTime\OpenForm1.txt"`

```
 If FormOpen = "1" Then
```

This is only true if the entire contents of your file is the single character "1". If the file contains more or fewer characters or something that isn't a "1", It will not match.

One of the few things in life that I can guarantee is that "=" is not broken. If it's returning "false" the only reason is that the two things are not equal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/comparison-operators

Also, as a general programming note: "Use meaningful identifiers." "FormOpen" sounds like an event or a property not file contents and is confusing to anybody who reads your code.

You could for example, have named it FileContents, which would make it's intent clear.